Missing index.html or _Host.cshtml in MudBlazor Project
I'm working on a MudBlazor project and noticed that I'm missing the index.html or _Host.cshtml file. Many solutions suggest adding code to the App.razor file, but my App.razor file looks like an HTML/index/_host.cshtml file, which is very confusing.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CustomStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


Chatgpt says it should look like this instead
<App>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <MudThemeProvider>
                <MudDialogProvider>
                    <MudSnackbarProvider>
                        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                    </MudSnackbarProvider>
                </MudDialogProvider>
            </MudThemeProvider>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <MudThemeProvider>
                <MudDialogProvider>
                    <MudSnackbarProvider>
                        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                        </LayoutView>
                    </MudSnackbarProvider>
                </MudDialogProvider>
            </MudThemeProvider>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</App>


which im inclined to believe,
I'm trying to add a simple dialog to my MudBlazor project, but it’s not working properly, which led me to this issue. Am I thinking about this wrong? How can I add the necessary components to my project? Any guidance would be appreciated.
the picture also shows but here is what is inside my app.razor file
people stating to update app.razor file example1:
people stating to update app.razor file example2
project directory
File inside app.razor
What I Tried:

Created a new _Host.cshtml file, but it didn't resolve the issue.
Replaced the App.razor file with what I thought should be there, but that broke everything.
Added the necessary MudBlazor services and components to Program.cs.
Checked the MudBlazor documentation for setup instructions.
Searched for similar issues but found solutions that didn't quite fit my problem.


In Net8 the files are missing because they are no longer needed.  Add a solution from a template and run it.  It works?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Default solutions work but I'm having a hard time adding a "dialogue" pop up for mudblazor, the app can run no issue but adding this seems to be giving me trouble. trying to find a solution for .net8 i guess is where i need to look, thank you for informing me about the update but the problem still persists.

See https://medium.com/@anasyunus/installing-mudblazor-in-a-net-8-blazor-project-cba586e34166
